# Stuck on how to add to a list in another class

Tags: java, list, class, methods

I have a class, DB, that contains a list:

```
private List<User> users;
```

along with an addUser method that allows users to be added to the list

```
public User addUser(String name) {
```

Another class, User, needs to create an instance of the User class, so I tried using the following code:

```
public User(String name) {
        DB.addUser(name);
```

But it returns the error that I can't make a static reference to the nonstatic method. I'm at a loss, because to create an instance of the User class, I have to put it into the list, but since the list is private, I have to use DB's methods, but I can't do that without getting an error... Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you make the `addUser` function in DB static?

Comment: @RishavKundu That would not make sense. It is clearly a method that changes state.

Comment: you need to create an instance of DB, or make addUser static

Comment: why not add a getUsers() method to DB that returns the ref to the List<User>, then call getUsers().add(new User(someName));

Comment: Arthur, what does `addUser` do exactly? Add its code to your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic then there should be a reference to a `DB` instance available to `User`.

Comment: Request you to provide the entire code for DB class and User class

Answer (score 0):

This function here is calling `addUser` in a static way.

```
public User(String name) {
    DB.addUser(name);
}
```

But this function below requires an object to be instantiated in order to call it (non-static)

```
public User addUser(String name) { ... }
```

So change it to be

```
public static User addUser(String name) { ... }
```

or create an instance of DB and call the method

```
public User(String name) {
    DB db = new DB();
    db.addUser(name);
}
```

Comment: The second option makes no sense. Why would you make a new DB everytime you make a new user?

Comment: ..? I'm not thinking about the application logic of his problem, I'm here only to fix a compilation error. He is not asking for help on logic

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are some basics which are not clear to you.

1. Members are always private and to interact them you should create public setter and getter.

   public List getUsers(){
   return users;
   }

   public void getUsers(List users){
   this.users=users;
   }
2. As a good coding standard, the naming should describe the behavior which provides specific action
   Hence

User addUser(String name)

seems very ambiguous considering it's actual implementation as given adds User to the list.

3. If DB class is a dependency then it should be instantiated
   Let's assume you are calling this code from main

   User user= new User();
   DB dbInstance=new DB();
   dbInstance.setUsers(new ArrayList());
   dbInstance.getUsers().add(user);

To provide a more specific answer awaiting further requested details